# How to simplfy $ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i w_i \right)^3 \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i w_i\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed. Consider $w_1, w_2,\ldots ,w_n \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n, \beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots , \beta_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and
$$a:= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i w_i \quad \text{and} \quad b:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i w_i.$$

**Question.** It's possible simplify
$$a^3\cdot b=\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i w_i \right)^3 \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i w_i\right)?$$

Is it possible to write this product in terms of just one sum?

Comment: I think your writing $a^3b$ is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest form would be:
$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i w_i \right)^3 \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i w_i\right)=\sum_{1\leq i,j,k,l\leq n}(\alpha_i\alpha_j\alpha_k\beta _l)( w_i w_j w_k w _l)$$

And there is no reason to believe with no restrictions on the elements any simpler arrangement can be achieved.